# How to set divider properties in a listFragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

In my app I have a FragmentActivity that implements ListFragment.OnSelectedListener.

The ListFragment uses a custom adapter that inflates a customrow.xml layout.

I'd like to change the divider color and height in the list.

I think I need to use the android:divider property but don't know how exactly.

I tried putting it in the layout of the FragmentActivity and in the customrow.xml layout, but it does not work...

customrow.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:gravity="center_vertical" 
android:background="@drawable/item_selector" 
android:divider="#f19000" >

...textview and imageview...

</LinearLayout>
```

**Edit: solution**

Thanks everybody for your help!
The problem was that I didn't inflate a custom xml for my ListFragment...

So creating a new list_fragment.xml and adding something like this in my ListFragment did the trick:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_fragment, null);
return view;
}
```

list_fragment.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<ListView 
    android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:divider="#f19000"
        android:dividerHeight="1dip" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Also, android:id="@android:id/list" is mandatory, changing id to something else results in a crash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also change the height of list divider with this code

```
android:dividerHeight="1dip"
```

Answer (score 1):

you should set the divider color in the listview item via:

```
android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
```

for instance.